# How to move app window when app is trying to use second monitor that's not present

Tags: macos, display, ms-office

I have OS X10.8.5 (fully patched). I'm using Office for Mac 2011 (fully patched).

Earlier in the week, I was working on a PowerPoint presentation. During the earlier work, I had a second monitor plugged in, and the presentation was displayed on it. Now I'm working at home with no second monitor. I checked under *Settings → Monitors*, and its clearly not present or detected.

PowerPoint starts, but it does not show the presentation's window. When I right click the PowerPoint icon on the task bar and select *Show All Windows*, the presentation's window is flung in from the second monitor. When I click on the presentation's window, it whizzes back to the second monitor that's not present.

How do I move the presentation window to the primary display that's present?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of approaches. The first works across all applications. The second is specific to Microsoft PowerPoint.

## Gather Windows

Launch **System Preferences > Displays** and use the **Gather Windows** button:

[image]

## Arrange All

Use the **Arrange All** or **Cascade** menu items to have Microsoft PowerPoint reveal and reposition the hidden window:

- Window (menu) > Cascade

[image]